# Any pytorch tools to monitor neural network's training?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard

Are there any tools to monitor network's training in PyTorch? Like tensorboard in tensorflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using [tensorboardX](https://github.com/lanpa/tensorboard-pytorch). It supports most (if not all) of the features of TensorBoard. I am using the Scalar, Images, Distributions, Histograms and Text. I haven't tried the rest, like audio and graph, but the repo also contains examples for those use cases. The installation can be done easily with `pip`. It's all explained in the README file of the repo.

There are also other github repos which implement a wrapper for PyTorch (and other languages/frameworks) to tensorboard. As far as I know they support fewer functionalities. But have a look at:

- [Crayon](https://github.com/torrvision/crayon)
- [Tensorboard-Logger](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/tensorboard_logger)

Answer (score 12):

PyTorch 1.1.0 supports TensorBoard natively with [`torch.utils.tensorboard`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html). The API is very similar to tensorboardX. See the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have asked this question before in the forums. Tensorboard seems very convenient for Tensorflow and it is also made part of the library/framework itself. However, PyTorch wouldn't take the same approach. But there is a library called `visdom` [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom) that is released by Facebook, that helps you log the training information. This gives you the flexibility of logging information the way you want. While this means a lot of flexibility, it also means you need to write some extra code to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on blckbird's answer, I'm also a big fan of Tensorboard-PyTorch. However I also found that its API is relatively low level and I was writing a lot of similar code over and over to do the logging. So (shameless plug) I've written a small package on top of it to automate monitoring network training experiments with minimal code. Hopefully someone else finds it helpful. [pytorch-monitor](http://github.com/teffland/pytorch-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

[Minetorch](https://github.com/louis-she/minetorch) helps me a lot at the past 2 Kaggle competitions. I think it's ready for others to use. It has built-in tensorboard or matplotlib supported. And many other features which make the work easy, includes:

- Logger
- Tensorboard supported
- Matplotlib (to generate png to file)
- Auto resume training
- Auto best model saving
- Hook points for customize
- ...

It's still in developing so any issues or PRs are very welcomed : )